# C, Sum of odd elements in a specific column in recursive function

Tags: c, function, recursion

The task is to check the sum of odd numbers in the 4th and second-to-last columns of the matrix.

It should be a recursive function. As the result of compilation the odd elements do display, but there are problems with the calculating of sum and counting the number of odd elements in the specific columns.

As well, when the number of columns are equal to the number of rows, the result of every function is 0.

```
int sumOfOdds(int n, int m, int i, int j, int a[][m], int sum) {
    if (i<n)
    {
        if ((a[i][j]%2) == 1) {
                printf("\nSUMThe odd element is: %i", a[i][j]);
                sum+=a[i][j];
                return sumOfOdds(n, m, i+1, j, a, sum);
        }
        else {
                ++i;
                return sum;
        }
    }
}


int counterOfOdds(int n, int m, int i, int j, int a[][m], int count) {
    if (i<n)
    {
        if ((a[i][j]%2) == 1) {
                printf("\nCOUNTThe odd element is: %i", a[i][j]);
                count++;
                return counterOfOdds(n, m, i+1, j, a, count);
        }
                else {
                ++i;
                return count;
        }
}
}
```

c1=0, c2=0; they are counters;
s1=0, s2=0; they are sum;
This is how the call of functions looks like:

```
printf("\nThe sum of odd numbers is the 4th column is: %i", sumOfOdds(n, m, 0, 3, a, s1)); 
printf("\nThe number of odd elements in the 4th column is: %i", counterOfOdds(n, m, 0, 3, a, c1));
printf("\nThe sum of odd numbers is the second-to-last column is: %i", sumOfOdds(n, m, 0, preLast, a, s2));
printf("\nThe number of odd elements in the second-to-last column is: %i", counterOfOdds(n, m, 0, preLast, a, c2));
```

I'd be grateful for any suggestions, 'cause I understand that the problem is about the body of if-else statements in functions, but I've tried every solution I was thinking about and it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Compile with warnings:

```
warning: control reaches end of non-void function
```

You need to `return` also when `i == n`, and do not add when `a[i][j]` is not odd:

```
int sumOfOdds(int n, int m, int i, int j, int a[][m], int sum) {
    if (i < n) {
        if ((a[i][j] % 2) == 1) {
            sum += a[i][j];
        }
        return sumOfOdds(n, m, i + 1, j, a, sum);
    } else {
        return sum;
    }
}
```